# What to do with phaseblade

Tags: terraria-console

I made a phaseblade and have no idea what to do next It said material so I tried to what to craft nothing needed it.

Comment: I forgot to ask do I just need a new crafting item?

Answer (score 2):

When any object have 'Material', ask the guide with the crafting option. He will list all crafting possibilities for any material, even if you don't have all the required elements.

As for your phaseblade, your world will have to go hardmode so you can harvest 50 Crystal shards in a hallowed cave, in order to craft the phasesaber, which is much stronger.

Comment: So basically keep it in storage untill heardmode.

Comment: What, you don't like it as a weapon now ? Use it while you can, because with all the new 1.2 weapons, the phasesaber is no match against the rare drops in hardmode.

Comment: Uh no I have weapons that do more damage